# Beaglebone's graphic card drivers installation with Yocto

Tags: yocto, beagleboneblack, eglfs

Beaglebone Black integrates Imagination's GPU PowerVR SGX530 which supports OpenGL|ES 2.0 ([source](https://www.imaginationtech.com/blog/fun-with-powervr-and-the-beaglebone-black-low-cost-development-made-easy/)) and this is why I want to use `qeglfs` platform for the Qt5 to display my application's window on the display.

I found the Yocto repository `meta-ti` which includes recipes for userspace libraries ([source](https://github.com/dagmcr/meta-ti/blob/master/recipes-graphics/libgles/ti-sgx-ddk-um_1.17.4948957.bb)) and kernel drivers ([source](https://github.com/dagmcr/meta-ti/blob/master/recipes-bsp/powervr-drivers/ti-sgx-ddk-km_1.17.4948957.bb)) for SGX530. Unfortunately both recipes have a line:

```
COMPATIBLE_MACHINE = "ti33x|ti43x|omap-a15|k3"
```

Is there any chance to use these recipes on Beagleboard Black? My project uses machine:

```
MACHINE ?= beaglebone-yocto
```

which is defined in the repository `poky` ([source](https://github.com/yoctoproject/poky/blob/master/meta-yocto-bsp/conf/machine/beaglebone-yocto.conf)).

Comment: I read ([here](https://www.elinux.org/BeagleBoneBlack/SGX_%2B_Qt_EGLFS_%2B_Weston)) that "SOC of Beaglebone Black is an AM335x by Texas Instruments which includes the graphic accelerator by Imagination Technologies i.e. PowerVR SGX530." So is it possible that I have to find `am335x` drivers somehow? I can only see `ti33x` in the `meta-ti` repository...

Answer (score 0):

Run your Qt app with `QT_QPA_PLATFORM` set:

```
QT_QPA_PLATFORM=qeglfs /opt/myapp
```

Comment: This is just how you choose the QPA "platform". Question is not about this. It is about how to install the graphical drivers. I mean I do need the drivers right? :)